# How to assign a function's result to a variable?

Tags: php

I am trying to assign a function's result to a variable.
Here is the code that I tried:

```
function apikey( $length ) {  
    $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
    $size = strlen( $chars );  
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {  
        $str= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];  
        echo $str; 
    }  
}  

$apikey = apikey(32);

echo $apikey;
```

I expected the output of **apikey(32)**, but I have a blank line only.

Comment: What does the first 8 rows of code have to do with the other two? Is that the function. Include all of the function then

Comment: OH sorry i am editing right now :D

Comment: In function use `return $srt` , instead of `echo $str;`

Comment: ok thanks i will give it a try :D

Comment: After for statement ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do get an output but that is from the echo in the function.
https://3v4l.org/GVpgE

If you want the key to be accessible outside the function then you need to return it.

```
function apikey( $length ) {  
  $chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  
  $size = strlen( $chars );  
  $key ="";
  for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {  
  $str= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];  
    echo $str; 
    $key .= $str;

  }  
  return $key;
}  

$apikey = apikey(32);

echo $apikey;
```

See example:
https://3v4l.org/246nh

Comment: İ will Select this as answer in 4 minutes :D